# Wordpress post editor omits line break?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

While writing a WordPress post, in visual mode there shows the line breaks in text editor but in HTML mode there is only
    &nbsp not BR tag.

How can I add BR tag at each line break instead of &nbsp by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these code inside you functions.php to remove filter that remove line brakes

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );

function my_tinymce_config( $init ) {
    $init['remove_linebreaks'] = false; 
    $init['convert_newlines_to_brs'] = true; 
    $init['remove_redundant_brs'] = false; 
    return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_tinymce_config');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can user function nl2br() of php.
for example:

```
nl2br(get_the_content());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a line break into the Wordpress Content screen you can do so by assigning the `<br />` tag a class, ie;

```
<br class="break" />
```

And Wordpress will not strip it out.